# why fio size parameter can influence the result of performance

Tags: storage, performance-testing, disk

I have used fio for testing disk performance for a while. But just recently, I have found a tricky thing I can not understand. As the size option described as below [(fio man page)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fio):

> size=int
>
> > Total size of I/O for this job. fio will run until this many bytes have been transfered, unless limited by other options (runtime, for instance). Unless nrfiles and filesize options are given, this amount will be divided between the available files for the job. If not set, fio will use the full size of the given files or devices. If the files do not exist, size must be given. It is also possible to give size as a percentage between 1 and 100. If size=20% is given, fio will use 20% of the full size of the given files or devices.

As long as I can understand, the size is not too small to gather enough is OK, but I my tests, I set the size to 128MB, 2GB, 800GB, the results differ:

```
size=128M, average iops = 165
size=2GB, average iops = 145
size=800GB, average iops = 78
```

In my opinion, for 4KB block, 128MB size is enough to get enough amount of IOs to do the test, the performance should not be influenced by the size. But why **size** is larger, performance is poorer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you disabled filesystem caching during test? 
A few parameters I always use during my test (http://linux.die.net/man/1/fio):

```
direct=1
invalidate=1
randrepeat=0
do_verify=0
verify_fatal=0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing a spinning drive, testing a larger area of capacity means the head has to seek farther to cover all the data.  This takes longer, and longer seek times lead to lower IOPS.

Answer (score 0):

In the path down to the disk there may be multiple "maximum" block sizes and it pays not to go above them.

For example, you may think you are submitting a 10MByte block down but what's really happening behind the scenes is that 10MByte block is being fractured into itty bitty 64Kbyte sized blocks because that's the limit the driver will accept. That 10MByte I/O can't be marked as done until each individual piece of it has been returned so you are creating blocking where it didn't have to exist and you are also creating extra work for the layer that did the splitting. Thus if you test block sizes from 512 upwards you usually see a big initial benefit in throughput followed by diminishing returns before things actually start becoming slower.

Not:, Linux sometimes exposes an "optimal block size" (see "/sys/block//queue/optimal_io_size" in https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-block ) which may or may not be the disk's true optimal block size.

Answer (score 0):

> But why size is larger, performance is poorer

You didn't include the job/command line you were running so below is just a guess:

If the job is a (buffered) write job that is not going direct to disk then the simple answer could be "with the larger `size`, less of the total writes could be cached before the the cache was full and had to wait". Linux can cache buffered writes (and return that it's "done" the write) but how much it can do this will depend on how much RAM you have available free at a given point. If you write significantly more than your RAM then you will start to see your backing device speed more because when the cache is full new writes can't be buffered until existing writes have been destaged.